# TS: Get interface from chained methods schema

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a form validation library, when the user wants to submit the form, he will need the types, I am stuck in that part.

I have the following code

```
interface Validation {
  name: string
  message: string
  params?: Record<string, any>
  test: (value: any, params?: any) => boolean
}

class StringSchema {
  validations: Validation[] = []

  required(): this {
    this.validations.push({
      name: 'required',
      message: 'this field is required',
      test: (value: string) => {
        return value === '' ? false : true
      },
    })

    return this
  }

  email(): this {
    this.validations.push({
      name: 'email',
      message: 'enter valid email',
      test: (value: string) => true,
    })

    return this
  }
}

class NumberSchema {
  validations: Validation[] = []

  between(min: number, max: number) {
    type Params = { min: number; max: number }

    this.validations.push({
      name: 'between',
      params: { min, max },
      message: 'must be between {min} and {max}',
      test: (value: number, params: Params) => {
        return value >= params.min && value <= params.max
      },
    })

    return this
  }

  optional() {
    return this
  }
}

const schema = {
  string() {
    return new StringSchema()
  },
  number() {
    return new NumberSchema()
  },
}

// --------------------------

const form = {
  name: schema.string().required().email(),
  age: schema.number().between(18, 50),
}
```

[here's TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexGQG8AoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwuTqabnYbNWHLgAc4UWkwD8jAEoQEBKNgA8LNiHYAaZHBABPAHxdILRgAoAbpgCug-Qd3jJNGY0cBKZAF4jyACMCAgwIfTIAXzIyBAw4XmQAZWEtRIQACwgaOFIuGyxcfCImRnQCvEIQAG0AXV9kWujKKAgAR1tgFuwLT0YwdOAmXMpKfsGAOnycCuLx0VsmdItyEZHqOkYAchb2zohsTe0uVZ4+AS2xoZhgCAxsZEHkHY6uw+ORszBLfPtGDQ5vH5hqsRi0wLYoMQfigfLDkJtNshpMh4BgmCg+lB7O9KBEjqsIp4mqCIODIchLlwolwsnBgBgen0BkMVh9mZNMNMiiAmHMFktWat1oJNrT6W8QdwILx+CKIOBoMgpvcxRgJSDPt87IJ-lpAf5WPZ8SNCcTmqSIcRKbjItFYvEhgA5Ww0ALQNKZbLA5UzHmlTmFSq1eqNLhusAAdwg8osNFAjBALrdUF02QAHgmk9BvIKKQZRCgAAoSKT1EjceNULNQADc3DgGarrsV1NWlw55W5vPmi2WOKotBF4aj8vVqxcUkY5bjIFTDeQeP7p1lWxoCzAgRQw+jxBIM4iehA9z3DYiY4+0q+yGs2szzZTyAnbkYxdcTH1wMlYMtSu1yCMPiPiWbjjDOyAAGTgb+GD2MgqiAU+vLpv2i4EkS7zfuS1oLsSBCiNymA9J+TwWlhzJUraMTFBuTAZLSZZcLq7BEbmmHECAEARkkKTsB6tI9FSxqJveLEYaR7Gccgzr3nx2QCbiRzUgA9EpyAALQaZpWnaTp2l2tRKLKDQDGUMKfx0dk4xMT04zPHs3SeOMqo9MaK7MBZcDjMJyY2duMYAIwABy6AArAADI5eEEQyniKdEYD5igABiRn1AlBYEDAhlQDQ+k8humrIClOUmQOGzwgAmrYWjqm5-lhbaQA)

Now that the `form` is defined, I would like to get an interface out of it, something like:

```
type Fields = typeof form
```

this returns me this:

[image]

but, i would like something like this

[image]

can someone achieve me this result? I thank everyone

[yup does something like that](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/docs/typescript.md), `yup.TypeOf<typeof form>`

I'm 100% stuck, I'm not very experienced with TypeScript, but I would like to make it work

I thank everyone

Comment: If you use `StringSchema extends Schema<string>` and `NumberSchema extends Schema<number>`, you might be able to solve this with a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that [somehow infers the `Schema` type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for each property of `form`

Comment: @Bergi Was just experimenting with this approach, but it seems that when using an empty "marker" interface/class (i.e. `interface Schema<T>{}`), `T` is thrown away because it isn't used, and infer just picks up `unknown`.

Comment: Hey @Bergi! where does `Schema` come from? I tried to create based on `typeof schema`, but when it comes to extending TypeScript it [complains](https://i.ibb.co/ckYyjCc/Captura-de-Tela-2021-05-19-a-s-20-53-03.png), if that's not going to take your time, could you make it work on TS Playground or add a response code?

Comment: I meant as an interface that you declare yourself. Though actually it might not be necessary - you just need some kind of conditional type that infers `string` from `StringSchema` and `number` from `NumberSchema` (and for that `optional()` thing, you'll need another schema type - generics would simplify this). See also @spender's answer which implements exactly what I suggested :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a marker class such as:

```
class Schema<T> {
  // This useless prop must be included to ensure T isn't thrown away
  // The exclamation mark asserts it is assigned (preventing non-assignment warnings)
  _!: T; 
}
```

and extend your schema items from it:

```
class StringSchema extends Schema<string> {
```

then you could write a type to infer your form-type:

```
const form = {
  name: schema.string().required().email(),
  age: schema.number().between(18, 50).optional(),
}

type FormType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Schema<infer TS> ? TS : never;
};

type Form = FormType<typeof form>

const test: Form = {
  name: 'Yung',
  age: 10
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDbACZzMAexGQG8AoZZEOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwuTqabnYbNWHLgAc4UWkwD8jAEoQEBKNgA8LNiHYAaZHBABPAHxdILRgAoAbpgCug-Qd3jJNGY0cBKZAF4jyACMCAgwIfTIAXzIyBAw4XmQAZQQACwgaOFUAFX9ySgB9AEJGLIBuSOjY%20KYk4S1ktIzkCAAPSBBsGob0zI0OXK4bLFx8IiZGdGG8QhAAbQBdX2QFwYtvEmQoCDBbKGIAIn3kKMotgEdbYC3sNcYwFOAavMpke8eAOiGcabH30VsmCkLM8XlRaIIAOTnS7XCHaLignh8ASMCFvGowYAQDDYZCPTYQC5XCDYOEIl5mMCWIb2Rh9LTePykcmgrY7PbIGkoHw85AQiHIaTIeAYJgoO5Qews47w0ERTzRVnbXbEdFcKJcHrADC3V4PJ7k9GfTDfUYgJh-AFAkEvah0VFajBk0GUJH8SEQcDQTkm3GO50uynUuyCensRn%20Vj2WUveWKl5slV6x7qioxOIJABythoAWg3SarXanSSqR6qhAObzUAGlCsa1IBPZxAAjMd418RjNxmhfT85osfMt5vG82AAO4QT0WGigRiV3PQXQZFrzqvQdaGgyiFAABQkUiWG1nIDXi6gpW4cFXVHXUHbhv1xqmZot-0BwOldshY8nnoDoIuFIjDHqAy7XjK0puiifI0ACYCBCgv5TsQJAnhEegdKQK4RABFIQOYyDWCGZ7Vs4B5uIw%206uEwEbMi6CbKhyXLIEYQ5AW47wnsgABkPE%20hg9jIKo7EURaK7ShEMaUHG5KJhyaoyfGBCiGamANja8mqvqqYako5oIUwZZNEOzxhhpclMcQIAQOOtSaOwBZwGs6oxgu1YWUqzZULZyDZueTkuTJ8IagA9KFyAALTRTFsVxfFcWVGMCEwMoNBHlw350sZcDvOZnjvNCxI3AVjprDG7rZY0uXudAazvMh04tgAHLoACsAAMBUqWpOqeCF0RgNuKAAGJpVkw3ZP4plcLMu54sQADWEAGAQMDIFk8wlHNixFp6JZOaooAwN6WSJP4Qpncg84QFY0DlBE5RkENO7IGNUDpUO700BNO6qC9EBrcKaUmDEyWvARVJvWlGWUFlfIAJq2FoAaVcgLYdRUQA)

Taking it a step further, your validation functions, rather than returning `this`, could be rewritten to behave immutably, returning a new schema (with `validations` copied into the new schema) that carries a modified type in its marker class. An exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks for the excellent answer, can you help me a little more? could you change your answer so that any field that does not have the `.required()` method is generated  interface with an undefined possible? can completely ignore `optional` it doesn’t exist, in the absence of `.required()`, it generates for example `number | undefined`.